# High peak current supply circuit

Tags: power-supply, circuit-design, high-current

I need to design a "peak" power current supply circuit for my load. Power specifications of load are below;

1. Continuous power consumption: 12 V 5 Amperes DC.
2. Peak power consumption: 12 V 10 Amperes DC.
3. Duration of Peak power consumption is 1 miliseconds with a repetition           period of 2 seconds. Time chart is below;

[image]

4. Input voltage of will be designed circuit is 18V-36V DC.
5. I can put a DC to DC converter that can be supplied 12 V 10 Amper, however i dont want to use, I have to use 12 Volt 5 Amper DC to DC converter and an extra circuit when peak current can be seen. I need this circuit design.
   I know in electronic, capacitor and inductor can store energy on their own. So can anyone help me to find or learn for this circuit?

Thanks,
Cem

Comment: How much is the output voltage allowed to sag during the current surge?

Comment: You don't need much of a circuit, as long as your DCDC converter can handle the **average** load, you can cover the peaks with a capacitor.

Comment: @FakeMoustache How will i calculate the value of capacitor?

Comment: @The Photon: Output voltage should not reduce from 12 Volt.

Comment: How to calculate the capacitor is explained in most textbooks about power supply design.

Comment: T=R*C and in theorically where T is second, R is ohm, and C is farad. Supply voltage is equal capacitor voltage within 5*T duration. I can not sure it is easy as you say. Is there any alternative ways?

Comment: @Cem realize that there will be a voltage sag during this time, but for your textbook example you would calculate R based on the additional current (5A) and your voltage(12v), and plug in your 1ms value for the T

Comment: @FakeMoustache, 5 A is going to require a big capacitor, even if only for 1 ms. See my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a capacitor to store energy and provide the difference in current for sort periods of time if you are willing to tolerate some voltage drop.

The voltage drop depends on the capacitance and the parasitic ESR (equivalent series resistance) present in the capacitor.

The voltage drop DV in a capacitor of value C having some ESR, due to a current I for time T is..

DV = I * T / C - ESR * I

Or alternatively, the required capacitance C to achieve a worst case voltage drop DV is...

C ≥ I * T / (DV + ESR * I)

Note that there are two unknwons, the ESR and the capacitance C.
We can approximate the required C by ignoring the ESR, or alternatively assuming a value before hand.

C ≥ I * T / DV (approximate)

So if we want a voltage drop of say 100mV or less and we have a current spike of 5A for 1ms then...

C = 5A * 1ms / 100mV = 50mF.

Note that for real parts that have a tolerance of usually 10% or 20%, you will need correspondingly more nominal capacitance to make up for the tolerance.  Also when calculating the real worst case DV you will need to assume C is 80% or 90% of nominal.

Here are two capacitors available for sale on Digikey that are around 50mF.  I would only use a 16V capacitor if you plan to operate at room temperature.  At elevated temperature you will need a 25V capacitor if you want the supply to be reliable.

56mF, 20%, 25V, 15mOhms ESR, $9.04

[ECE-T1EP563EA](http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/panasonic-electronic-components/ECE-T1EP563EA/P10007-ND/258673) 



DV = 5A * 1ms / (56mF * 80%) - 15mOhms * 5A = 187mV.


47mF, 20%, 16V, 20mOhms ESR, $4.68

[380LX473M016K052](http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/cornell-dubilier-electronics-cde/380LX473M016K052/338-2458-ND/1699660) 



DV = 5A * 1ms / (47mF * 80%) - 20mOhms * 5A = 232mV.

Comment: Can it be done by an inductor with same idea?

Comment: An inductor can be used to store energy, but inductors by nature resist rapid changes in current, thus making them unsuitable for directly supplying momentary surge current.

Answer (score 7):

You can place a capacitor in parallel with your power supply to provide additional current demanded by the load for short periods. However, the voltage output will drop when the current demand exceeds the power supply's capacity. If the "output voltage should not reduce from 12 volt", then you will need to tune the power supply to provide slightly above 12 V during the low-current periods.

The amount of the voltage sag can be determined from the basic capacitor equation

$$Q=CV$$

In this case, \$Q\$ is the amount of charge to be provided during the surge, given by \$I t\$, where \$I\$ is the excess current demand (5 A in your case), and \$t\$ is the duration of the surge demand (1 ms in your case). So you need 5 mC of charge to be supplied by the capacitor during the current surge. Then

$$\Delta{}V = \frac{I t}{C}$$

Or, if you first determine the allowed voltage sag (\$\Delta{}V\$), you can calculate the needed capacitance as

$$C = \frac{It}{\Delta{}V}$$

So if, say, you allow for 100 mV of voltage sag, you need to have a capacitance of 50 mF (millifarads, not microfarads). Be prepared for sticker shock when you price out what 50 mF of capacitance rated for 15-20 V working voltage will cost you. If you can accept a larger voltage sag, you can then use a proportionally lower capacitance value.

But once you price out 50 mF capacitors, you might want to look again at regulators capable of sourcing the full 10 A out of the box.

Comment: Very thank you, for your answer, i have learned a lot from your answer.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is: what is your 5 A DC-DC converter regulation properties?

Do you use a ready-made part or you design it by yourself?

Imagine you have a "good" 5 A DC-DC converter. It would try rising its output current when the output voltage drops even 20 mV below its nominal level (12 V). This clearly leads to overload condition: output current above 5 A. And even very large output capacitor does not help.

So the next question is: how does your DC-DC reacts to overload? The best way for your task is to go to current limiting state. However, not all of them would act this way. Some may switch down due to overload. And their recovery may take a long time.

If you design DC-DC by yourself, the best way is to design a converter with peak current capability 10 A and average current 5 A. It means that you use 5 A for thermal considerations and you use 10 A for inductor saturation and maximum current on your MOSFETs. Its size / costs are almost the same as 5 A converter. You may only need a little larger buck inductor.

If you want to use ready-made DC-DC, you have to check carefully its specs for regulation and overload. Most of "made in China" supplies do not tell anything about these properties.

Comment: It is possible to isolate the voltage drop in the capacitor from the supply output by adding a small amount of series impedance between the supply output and capacitor.  So use of a capacitor is certainly viable.  For example, if a 100uH inductor was added and the capacitor dropped by 0.1V linearly during the 1ms then the supply would only see an increase in current of 0.5A, not 5A.

Answer (score 0):

What is the load you're delivering power to? How critical is its supply voltage?

One approach would be to measure the current across a milliohm resistor in series with the load (with a comparator circuit) and when the current rises above 5A, switch in a capacitor and switch out the main PSU. Use the rest of the duty cycle to charge the capacitor.

The easiest way to switch the loads would be to set the capacitor charge voltage a bit higher than the regulator's voltage, and use diodes for steering. Or you could do something complicated with Mosfets.

Answer (score 0):

Can it be done by an inductor based on same idea?
$$
T = \frac{L}{R},
$$
$$
L \ge T*R\,
$$
and,
$$
L \ge \frac{T*\Delta V} {\Delta I}\
$$
$$
L \ge \frac{1ms* 0.1V} {5A}\
$$
$$
L \ge 20 \mu Henry
$$